# Custom post type: One post can assign only one category validation wordpress default editor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

> Custom post type name: News
>
> custom taxonomy name: Type

***My question:***
One "News(Post)" can assign one "type(category)", if we try assign more "type(category)" then validation message will be shown.
how to do this?

Any one can help?

[image]